# The text is not (right) justified when using "paracol" in a 2-column document

Tags: two-column, paracol, justification

How to justify the text on the right side when using [`paracol`](https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/paracol/paracol-man.pdf) for a 2-column document?

Here following I show two MWEs where, in some rows, the text goes "out of the right margin", not going down to the following line:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Caladea}   % <-- Uncomment for the first MWE
% \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Carlito} % <-- Uncomment for the second MWE

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{paracol}{2}
    \lipsum[1]
    \switchcolumn
    \lipsum[1]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Narrow columns are difficult to justify, especailly using lipsum (hyphenation).  It is SOP to use `\sloppy` in such cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot @John Kormylo!!! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are lacking some good hyphenation rules, specially with lipsum text generator.

Furthermore narrow columns are difficult to fully justify, so a bit of re-wording or manual intervention could be needed in an actual use-case.

For your MWE, I added `babel` to add/improve hyphenation rules and `microtype` to automatically add some font ajustments in the micro-level.

Also I don't have `Carlito` but I used `Calibri`, which have the same font metrics, but feel free to switch back to `Carlito` if needed.

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Caladea}   % <-- Uncomment for the first MWE
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Calibri} % <-- Uncomment for the second MWE

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \lipsum[1]
        \switchcolumn
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{paracol}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mane32!!